# Comparing integer with array of integers

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to compare integer from user input with array of integers,when found to print info about the found student here is the code.Something like strcmp but to compare two integers

```
    scanf("%d",&subject);
    for(i=0;i<num_students;i++)
     {
         if(strcmp(subject,array[i].programming)==0)
         {
         printf("%d.First name :%s\nLast name: %s",i+1,array[i].fname,array[i].lname);
         found=1;
         }
       }
     if(found==0)
     printf("Not found");

    }
```

Comment: "Something like strcmp but to compare two integers" are you looking for `==` ?

Comment: You should show the types of the variables you are using. We can't tell much from the code when we have to guess how your variables were defined.

Comment: sorry i am too dumb when i tried if((subject==array[i].programming)==0)
forgot to delete ==0 thank you anyway

Comment: Why is this question tagged [c++] rather than [c]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that 'programming' is a numerical value:

```
scanf("%d",&subject);
for(i=0;i<num_students;i++)
{
    if(subject == array[i].programming)
    {
        printf("%d.First name :%s\nLast name: %s",i+1,array[i].fname,array[i].lname);
        found=1;
    }
}
if(found==0)
{
    printf("Not found");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`strcmp` is for String comparison.

For integers, we use `==`.

Use `subject==array[i].programming` in your code.

Alternative use `std::find`.

Example :

```
#include <algorithm> // for std::find
#include <iterator> // for std::begin, std::end

...


  //arr[] being array of ints
  //num being number searched
  bool exists = std::find(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), num) != std::end(arr);

...
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 for(i=0;i<num_students;i++)
 {
   if(subject==array[i].programming)
   {
     printf("%d.First name :%s\nLast name: %s",i+1,array[i].fname,array[i].lname);
     found=1;
   }
 }
 if(found==0)
   printf("Not found");
```